# Setting permissions with FTP

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, ftp

I'm having some issues setting up permissions for FTP. Read another thread on here regarding it, but I wasn't sure if it really matched what I needed.

Essentially, right now I've got the client's FTP and home directories set up correctly, but once they upload a file, they find that the file cannot be edited, I think this is due to the previous permissions of the file.

So my question is, how do I allow them to edit all of the files within their home directory, regardless of the permissions, without compromising the root of the machine.

Please note, that the FTP access is to a virtual machine that they own, but I want to create seperate accounts for seperate directories, regarding FTP access.

Comment: What do you mean that "they can't edit it"? What method are they using to edit a file located on a remote machine? What do these users get when they run `umask` on the server?

Answer (score -1):

First find out what user and group are left as owners of the file after the ftp upload (`ls -lha`)
Add that user and the client's user to the group that owns the files
`#useradd -G group clientusername`
then change the permissions of the FTP directory:
this `chmod g+rwx ftp/directory`.